# How to get saved tracks for a specific user, or change the current user?

Tags: spotify

The Spotify API has an endpoint "Get a Users's Saved Tracks" `GET https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks` but as you can see from `me` in the url, and in the [documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-users-saved-tracks/), this is only for the current user. How can I access information about a non current user, or change the current user?

For example, userA logs in, I get an access and refresh token for userA. userB logs in, replacing userA as the current user, I get userB's tokens. How can I now make make requests for information about userA?

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the tokens you get from authenticating users.
Say you're using user sessions:

1. User A logs in.
2. You get the access and refresh tokens for user A.
3. You save these tokens to User A's session.
4. User B logs in.
5. You get the access and refresh tokens for user B.
6. You save these tokens to User B's session.

You'd do this the same way that you have already implemented user sessions.
And so when a user lands on your redirect URI, you save the tokens you received to their session.
And then when you need to use the Spotify API you use the tokens saved in the users session.

---

If you however want to do this for one end-user, then with a web server things get a little harder.
But with a CLI app things can be a little easier.

What you want to do is log user A and B into your application, manually saving both tokens independently.
This is as easy as making an authentication function that you call twice and save the results to two variables.
After this you can then call the API with the saved tokens.
And use user A's token when you want to get user A's saved tracks.

Here's a low-level example implementation in Python 3 using [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master), of getting the users tracks and user information, using different scopes. Where the comments are the part the code's at in the [authorization code flow](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#authorization-code-flow):

```py
import time
import urllib.parse as parse
import webbrowser

import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize'
OAUTH_TOKEN_URL = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token'

# Change to your application settings
class Settings:
    client_id = ''
    client_secret = ''
    redirect_uri = ''


def authenticate(scope=None):
    '''Implement OAuth 2 Spotify authentication'''
    # Application: Request authorization to access data
    payload = {'client_id': Settings.client_id,
               'response_type': 'code',
               'redirect_uri': Settings.redirect_uri,
               'show_dialog': 'true'} # allow second account to login
    if scope:
        payload['scope'] = scope
    auth_url = '{}?{}'.format(OAUTH_AUTHORIZE_URL, parse.urlencode(payload))
    # Spotify: Displays scopes & prompts user to login (if required)
    # User: Logs in, authorizes access
    webbrowser.open(auth_url)

    response = input('Enter the URL you were redirected to: ')
    code = parse.parse_qs(parse.urlparse(response).query)['code'][0]

    payload = {'redirect_uri': Settings.redirect_uri,
               'code': code,
               'grant_type': 'authorization_code'}
    if scope:
        payload['scope'] = scope

    # Application: Request access and refresh tokens
    # Spotify: Returns access and refresh tokens
    auth = HTTPBasicAuth(Settings.client_id, Settings.client_secret)
    response = requests.post(OAUTH_TOKEN_URL, data=payload, auth=auth)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        response.raise_for_status()
    token_info = response.json()
    token_info['expires_at'] = int(time.time()) + token_info['expires_in']
    token_info['scope'] = scope
    return token_info


if __name__ == '__main__':
    user_a = authenticate(scope='user-library-read')
    user_b = authenticate(scope='user-read-email user-read-private user-read-birthdate')
    print('user_a', user_a)
    print('user_b', user_b)

    for url in ['https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks',
                'https://api.spotify.com/v1/me']:
        for user in [user_a, user_b]:
            token = 'Bearer ' + user['access_token']
            # Application: Uses access token in requests to Web API
            # Spotify: Returns request data
            r = requests.get(url, headers={'authorization': token})
            if r.status_code != 200:
                print(r.text)
            else:
                print([
                    '{}: {}'.format(key, str(value)[:20])
                    for key, value in r.json().items()
                ])
```